# SQLBulkCopy causing deadlock

Tags: c#, sql-server, deadlock, sqlbulkcopy

I have the following code..which actually inserts data into destination using SQLBulkCopy. This code is failing in source SQL server frequently because of deadlock. FYI the table that is being copied can be in use (I meant some inserts/selects would be running) while we perform bulk copy.

Is that causing the issue or the "TABLOCK" hint has anything to do? As per my understanding TABLOCK acquire only shared locks and shouldn't be a problem.

```
using (var reader = srcConnection.ExecuteReader($"select * from [{DatabaseName}].[{schemaName}].[{tableName}]"))
{
    const SqlBulkCopyOptions bulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                                               SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls | //Do not replace nulls with defaults in destination
                                               SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity;
        //Use the identity values from source, do not generate identities in destination.

    using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(dstConnection.ConnectionString, bulkCopyOptions))
    {
        const int threeMinutes = 60*3;

        bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = threeMinutes; //Timeout is for a single batch
        bcp.BatchSize = 5000;
        bcp.DestinationTableName = $"[{DestinationDatabaseName}].[{schemaName}].[{tableName}]";
        bcp.EnableStreaming = true;

        foreach (var col in table.Columns.Cast<Column>().Where(c => !c.Computed))
        {
            bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(col.Name, col.Name);
        }

        bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are right. Read this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/932cd26c-53fc-49c0-b082-e7f5f05a9801/deadlock-when-using-sqlbulkcopy-to-concurrently-insert-rows-into-a-single-nonempty-table?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: We are not populating destination concurrently and our destination tables are heap (i.e., no index). More over the origin of deadlock seems to be source table but not destination.

Comment: I think your understanding of TABLOCK is wrong, [from the documentation on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) "*TABLOCK - Specifies that the acquired lock is applied at the table level. **The type of lock that is acquired depends on the statement being executed**.*" (Emphases mine), so a select with a TABLOCK would only do a shared lock, but a insert (like you are doing) would take a exclusive lock.

Answer (score 7):

The bulk insert will need to insert rows into the table.  Inserting rows requires exclusive locks.  The exact locks acquired will depend on the concurrency model.

If you specify the `TableLock` option, your process will attempt to acquire an exclusive table lock.  This can definitely lead to deadlocks if your process first acquires a shared table lock, other process has shared row locks, and both processes try to upgrade their locks to exclusive locks.

There several ways to get more information about the deadlocks:

- Enable [trace flag 1222 and review the SQL Server log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx)
- Run a [SQL Server Profiler with the Lock:Deadlock Graph event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx)
- Monitor [extended events](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2013/04/26/how-to-monitor-deadlock-using-extended-events-in-sql-server-2008-and-later/)